# Why Is Exchange Server Appending “ýÿ ” to Message Body?

Tags: email, exchange

I've noticed there's a subset of emails (haven't identified the similarity between them) that pass through our exchange server that get the following contents appended to the email:

```
ýÿ
```

I can't figure out the cause. Trying to search the internet on those two characters is stupid hard (most search engines seem to completely ignore 2-letter words or less) even by quoting the string (too much unrelated gibberish). I've seen this on one other exchange server in the past but had no control/requirements regarding the oddity. It became a problem recently but only briefly in some processes that parse automated emails but that's since been handled.

All I really want to know is: what are these characters and why does the exchange server tack on these characters? The characters are added after the message contents, but before the system-added footer. The characters are not part of the footer information itself, so where is it coming from?

Apologies if this isn't the right place: I've been booted from StackOverflow for "not programming related" and from ServerFault for "end user related". At this point I'm lost.

Comment: That generally has to do with encoding. Are these incoming messages or outgoing messages? Check the native language of the sender or recipient, and check the other mail server software and version.

Comment: The affected messages are all internal. The outgoing message does not contain the characters (nor the footer, appended after receipt by the exchange server) but the receivers all see it after it's modified. I've disabled the system footer in case it was causing it but that seems to not be the case.
Affected messages are in plaintext (not HTML or rich text) format.

Comment: you can use http://symbolhound.com for searches like that (only unrelated stuff came up though)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the messages were being routed through a mailserver at the endpoint on a user domain that was poorly configured - it was translating received messages into HTML format and then forwarding the message, but the final server forces all messages to plaintext format before delivering to the recipient. Thanks to music2myear for the encoding hint - the poorly configured server seems to have a problem encoding into Base32 HTML and when the result is decoded it finds extra characters. Disabling that translation on the old server seems to be preventing this, now.